# Getting results from pool.map() of pathos

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pathos

I have tried to create an issue of mine in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
import multiprocessing
shapes_to_display=[]
products =[ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def hay(i):
    print('PROCESSOR ID: ', multiprocessing.current_process().pid, 'Iteration: ', i)
    product = products[i]
    shapes_to_display.append([i, product])
    return shapes_to_display

pool = ProcessPool(nodes=4)
res= pool.map(hay, range(len(products)))

pool.close()
pool.restart()

res = np.asarray(res)
print(res.shape)

for r in res:
    r = np.asarray(r)
    print(r)
```

What I want to get as result is:

> (10,) [[0 0], [1,1], .. .. .. [9,9]]

What I end up getting:

> (10,) [[0 0]] [[1 1]] [[2 2]] [[3 3]] [[0 0] [4 4]] [[1 1] [5 5]] [[2
>   2] [6 6]] [[3 3] [7 7]] [[0 0] [4 4] [8 8]] [[1 1] [5 5] [9 9]]

Can any of you help me to figure this out ? What do I need to do to get the result the way I want to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"What do I need to do to get the result the way I want to ?"*

You need to **first *understand*** the **toys** & its **mechanics**

Process-based Pathos-distributed computing does not uniformly "share" the variables "across" all the *remote* processes ( rather the very opposite happens and right due to **separation** of these individual processes, the ***central*** and ***all distributed* GIL-lock**-s become & remain independent & free to run computation without waiting in otherwise un-escapable python interpreter **`[SERIAL]`**-queue working but waiting for one's turn in an ***avoided***-concurrency-safe but awfully inefficient sequence of all waiting but one does a small amount of work, if it is its turn, in an endless GIL-lock waiting queue of  <kbd>One_step</kbd>-***after***-<kbd>Another_step</kbd>-***after***-<kbd>Another_step</kbd>-...

Pathos helped you to cut this pure-**`[SERIAL]`** chain of ***ALL*-wait**-but-*<sub>( just )</sub> **one**<sub>( and only one )</sub>* -**works**.

The cut ( by going to send some work into fully-independent processes ) also means that those processes know nothing else but the state of the original (main) python process, at the time of their instantiation ( yes, the were created by a full-copy of the originating python interpreter, including its whole internal state - i.e. having all `import`-s done and also all the data-structures get fully replicated into the herd of new process-copies ).

This helps for doing some serious work, yet it is pretty expensive to all that heavy artillery work for cases, where but a few computing steps get done at the far end of the remote-process code-execution - such use-cases never justify the add-on costs that have been burnt for making that happen.

Yet, the process independence also means, there is no way ( unless explicitly programmed ) any independent process will ever hear about a variable assignment in any other of the (still independent) processes.

So doing an **`.append()`** is always the trouble if modifying remote copies of variable instantiated in the main interpreter before the processes get copied it into the remote-**independent**-instances.

Do a **`return [i, product]`** in `hay(i)` and the `pool.map()` will assemble these respective results into the shape and form you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question !